# How to iterate each object in json array jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

Intention: Need to iterate the each item in json array using jq and proccess seperately

api returns data in form

```
{
  "name": [
    {
      "first": "first",
      "class": false,
      "type": "B"
    },
    {
      "first": "second",
      "class": false,
      "type": "B"
    },
    {
      "first": "third",
      "class": false,
      "type": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

And i am able to parse it as

```
data=`curl http://some.ur;l`
echo "$data" | jq -rc '.name[] | select(.type=="B") | .class=true'
```

it returns data as

```
{"first": "first","class": true, "type": "B"}
{"first": "second", "class": true, "type": "B"}
```

Now i want to proccess these `two` outputs in such a way so that i can make a PUT call for each of them . I tried to learn some concepts of `xargs` but could not make it done

I piped the output to `| xargs -n1` but it removed all the quotes from the string

Comment: In one place you have `"name"`, in the other you have `.names`. Make sure your example is internally consistent.

Comment: Also, note that `echo $data` is itself buggy and can corrupt your strings. **Always** use quotes, as in, `echo "$data"`, and ideally use `printf` (`printf '%s\n' "$data"`). See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566) and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Getting to your question: Use `jq -c` to make each item evaluate to one line of output, and a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to iterate over those lines.

Comment: The `cmd` tag is for Microsoft Windows cmd.exe questions.

Comment: BTW, why two separate copies of `jq` instead of having the same one that does the `select` also set `class=True`?

Comment: (and yes, as you discovered, you should **never** use `xargs` without `-d $'\n'` or `-0` unless you _want_ it to split on strings, process backslashes and quotes as syntax, etc; this is [BashPitfalls #56](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0))

Comment: I have edited the question @CharlesDuffy, according to your suggestions. It reduced the pipes. Thanks. 
It still need something to proccess.

Answer (score 0):

The only part you're missing is a `while read` loop.

```
data=$(curl ...)
while IFS= read -r line; do
  curl -XPUT -d"$line" http://some_url
done < <(jq -c ... <<<"$data")
```

...or...

```
curl ... |
  jq -c ... |
  xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 curl -XPUT http://some_url -d
```

Note:

- `xargs -d $'\n'` tells `xargs` to treat only newlines (and not other whitespace) as separators between items; it also turns off treatment of quotes and backslashes as syntactic rather than literal.
- `xargs -n 1` tells `xargs` only to pass one data item to each copy of curl.
- Making the last argument to `curl` be `-d` means that xargs will place the data immediately after that position.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through using `while read`:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line
do
  
  # your PUT goes here

  # dummy
  printf 'PUTting JSON: %s\n' "$line"

done < <(jq -c '.name[] | select(.type == "B") | .class = true')
```

If you absolutely need to use `xargs` then use a newline character as delimiter

```sh
jq -c '.name[] | select(.type == "B") | .class = true' \
| xargs -d $'\n' printf 'PUTting JSON: %s\n' # dummy
```

Comment: @pmf, can't it be without using loop?

Comment: @JohnByro, ...you need _some_ kind of loop no matter what -- how else do you start `curl` more than once? Using xargs isn't not using a loop; it's just making the loop happen in a C program instead of in your shell interpreter.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for your valuable discussion

Comment: @pmf thanks for your answer